# Qt QGraphicsScene addItem() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

In Game::Game i call shoot() who create and add to scene NormalBullet object.

```
#include "game.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include "dirtblock.h"
#include "normalbullet.h"
#include <QTimer>

Game::Game(QGraphicsView *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    //set scene
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    setFixedSize(500, 500);
    setScene(scene);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);

    //set Player
    player = new PlayerTank();
    scene->addItem(player);

    //set dirtblock test
    DirtBlock * db = new DirtBlock();
    db ->setPos(100, 100);
    scene->addItem(db);

    NormalBullet *bl = new NormalBullet();
    bl->shot(QPointF(300,300), 90);

}
```

I have segmentation fault (signal name: SIGSEGV) when i try add to scene object NormalBullet *bullet in NormalBullet::shoot. I create 'test' variable to see on debuger what scene() return and turn out its 0x0. When i try get acess to scene by game->scene (test2), i have also segmentation fault. Why scene not return proper pointer?

```
#include "normalbullet.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "QTimer"
#include "dirtblock.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>

extern Game * game;

NormalBullet::NormalBullet(QGraphicsPixmapItem *parent)
{
    setPixmap(QPixmap(":/images/NormalBullet.png"));
    damage = 10;
    speed = 10;

}

void NormalBullet::shot(QPointF coord, qreal angle)
{
    //create new bullet, setPos, add to scene and connect to timer
    NormalBullet * bullet = new NormalBullet();
    bullet->setPos(coord);
    bullet->setRotation(angle);
    //scene()->addItem(bullet);
    auto test = scene(); //return 0x0
//auto test2 = game->scene; //<= segmentation fault
    QTimer *tim = new QTimer();
    connect(tim, &QTimer::timeout, bullet, &NormalBullet::move);
    tim->start(200);

    scene()->addItem(bullet);
}
```

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "playertank.h"
#include<QObject>

class Game : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Game(QGraphicsView *parent = nullptr);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) override;

    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    PlayerTank *player;
private:

};
#endif // GAME_H
```

For some reason I dont have access to scene pointer in NormalBullet and otcher class, except Game class.

Comment: Welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Comment: What is the role of `NormalBullet::add()`? I found `NormalBullet *bl = new NormalBullet();
    bl->add();` in `Game::Game()` but it's not clear to me what it does. As it is it looks like the pointee of `bl` becomes a memory leak.

Comment: I add code with b1->add() by by mistake. It shoud be bl->shot(QPointF(300,300), 90);.

Comment: I figure this out. Shoot() member function begin work properly, when i addItem to scene object bl, before i call bl->shoot. I still not know why this work, what is the case. Someone help my understand?